# "bind" DNS server and considering "/etc/hosts"

Tags: dns, local, bind

in my LAN I use a small machine as server/gateway (with Ubuntu 10.04).
On this server runs **bind9** DNS server and all LAN clients are using it as unique DNS.
Everything works ok, except that I'd like to find a method to consider **server's** `/etc/hosts` file.

For example, if my server's `/etc/hosts` file contains line:

```
192.168.10.5    testserver05.lan
```

I'd like to mirror the answer in **bind**. In fact now I get **not found** error:

```
root@nasinsu:/etc/bind# nslookup testserver05.lan
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find testserver05.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

Is this possible?

Comment: check content of /etc/nsswitch.conf (if I recall filename correctly). In case of `hosts:

dns files` your resolver must (?) (TBT!) return answers based on **all defined sources**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you actually serving real zones in bind, or is it just acting as a cache/forwarder?  If it is only a cache/forwarder, then you might want to take a look at [DNSMASQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq).  DNSMASQ has a simple caching DNS server, and it can reference the local hosts file, and other files for answering requests.

Comment: Thx! `apt-get install dnsmasq`, `apt-get remove --purge bind9` and... It works with no more configs!

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.